# Load JSON data from Pig Streaming

Tags: python, json, stream, streaming, apache-pig

I have a python script `stream.py`, that reads json lines from stdin, process it, and writes json lines into stdout.

Example input line from `data.json`:

```
{"user_id":3217,"description":"some text"}
```

Example output line:

```
{"user_id":3217,"description":"some text PROCESSED","rating":1.78}
```

In Pig, I tried to stream and manipulate the data this way:

```
data = LOAD 'data.json';

DEFINE my_stream `./stream.py` output (stdout USING JsonLoader('user_id:int, description:chararray, rating:float'));
data_streamed = STREAM data THROUGH my_stream;

ratings = FOREACH data_streamed GENERATE rating;
ratings_unique = DISTINCT ratings;

ratings_test = LIMIT ratings_unique 10;
DUMP ratings_test;
```

When I try to execute, I get this error:

```
pig script failed to validate: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonLoader does not implement interface org.apache.pig.StreamToPig
```

Until now, I only see two solutions (that I would like to avoid if possible):

1. Storing the streamed data into a "temporary" file and loading it using JsonLoader.
2. Modifying `stream.py` to write tsv lines instead of json lines, so that I could load it with the default PigStorage.

Is it possible to make pig streaming work with JsonLoader?